# foreach laravel error after using curl json output

Tags: php, laravel, curl

this is my Controller codes

```
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setUrl('http://localhost:8001/scrape');
$curl->execute();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('output.json'));
return view('data-scraping', compact('data'));
```

i use a data scraper at that 8001 port 
this is my output.json

```
[
    {
        "rank": 1,
        "title": "Did Facebook’s faulty data push publishers to make terrible decisions on video?",
        "url": "http://www.niemanlab.org/2018/10/did-facebooks-faulty-data-push-news-publishers-to-make-terrible-decisions-on-video/",
        "points": 59,
        "username": "laurex",
        "comments": 1
    }
]
```

and finally that a foreach in my blade template

```
@foreach($data as $key => $value)
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a href="{!! $value->url !!}">
            <h3 class="title">{!! $value->title !!}</h3>
        </a>
        <p class="text-muted">
            <strong>Points :</strong> {!! $value->points !!}
            <strong>Comments :</strong> {!! $value->comments !!}
        </p>
        <p class="text-muted">Posted by <a href="#">{!! $value->username !!}</a></p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

but when i load my webpage that the problem

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: F:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\resources\views\data-scraping.blade.php)
```

when i use `dd()` in my blade view return `none` but there is an output.json file.

if i comment curl functions and used prebuilt json file that works fine

how can i handle that ?

Comment: Are you able to check for a curl error with [‘curl_error’](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) method? Also, what’s the path to your output.json?

Comment: @joelrosenthal curl_error return empty string . output.json path is public/output.json . every part work fine separately . if i just read json data from controller that work .even curl create my json file . when i used them after each other throw error

Answer (score 1):

Try passing **true** as second parameter of json_decode.
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('output.json'), true);

Comment: What do you get if you try to print the $data variable? Have you tried to put this result in a json online validator online like https://jsoneditoronline.org/ or https://jsonlint.com/ ?

Comment: `dd($data)` after this code `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('output.json'));` show me my data . but after this code `$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setUrl('http://localhost:8001/scrape');
$curl->execute();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('output.json') , true);` is empty

Comment: I think using curl_close could help. I see you are using a Curl class that I did not know it was provided with laravel, could be something like $curl->close().

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to set the [`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option. Something like
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`. If you still don't get any response from that you probably have a json decode problem which would require you to use the [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) method to troubleshoot.